# Leaflet: Are Bing Maps tiles exempt from restriction to use only with Bing Maps?

Tags: leaflet, bing-maps, legal

Leaflet has [a plugin that can fetch Bing Maps tiles](https://github.com/gmaclennan/leaflet-bing-layer). However, I see in the [Bing Maps terms of use](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) the following prohibition:

> > 8.2 d) Use Content, including geocodes, other than via an authenticated call to the Services and/or in conjunction with a Bing Map.

Would this not make any use of the leaflet plugin a violation of the terms of use? Are tiles specifically different from other Bing data? Or is there a specific exemption that has been offered to Leaflet?

Further, if other services are used, e.g. geocoding with OpenStreetMap data, is that a breach of the above?

Answer (score 3):

The leaflet-bing-layer plugin requires a valid Bing Maps key, which means that all tiles are obtained via "an authenticated call to the Services." Thus, it complies with the terms of use.

The Leaflet plugin just simplifies interaction with the Bing Maps API. The developer is still subject to all the usage limits/restrictions that normally apply to the API, and the tiles still count toward the number of free transactions that they get with their key.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Nathan's response, leaflet also doesn't store the tiles, it simply accesses them after it calls the REST imagery metadata service when the map loads to generate a Bing Maps transaction. This is inline with the terms of use of Bing Maps. I have a document that outlines this process here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D35222484A76A01!367734&authkey=!AG_vTkAxtCXFaNk&ithint=file%2cdocx This is how map controls like ArcGIS, OpenLayers, Leaflet, and many more integrate Bing Maps imagery/maps into their platform. Bing Maps even makes its aerial imagery available to the Open street map team for use in their map editor tool.

As for your question about mixing data from other mapping platforms. Generally this isn't allowed unless you own the data yourself. OSM data is actually an issue as it's open data license actually puts the road data in Bing Maps at risk of having to be made open. Ordnance Survey (olds mapping company in the world based who collect map data of the UK) data on the other hand is allowed as Bing Maps has an agreement with them and also includes OS maps as a layer option.